# How to initialize TP-Link WN725N V3 at startup every time Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, wireless, startup

The TP-Link WN725N V3 works on Ubuntu 18.04.3 out of the box.

Sometimes, the adapter is not seen by the system at startup, I have to unplug and plug it back in. I considered the driver but it is for earlier kernels.

Is there something I can do to get the adapter to be on every time at start up?

Comment: @phineas that info is about a router and irrelevant

Answer (score 1):

Well I have rebooted x number of times x5. It's fixed. If you see a question mark the first time do not fret just reboot again.

The problem does not seem to be with my exact adapter or any particular WIFI adapter. Maybe works for anything plugged into USB and beyond.

This issue is a gadget/driver binding thing. Never heard of it.

I can't take credit the answer is here [Ubuntu doesn't bind usb device after reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/888752/ubuntu-doesnt-bind-usb-device-after-reboot?rq=1)

pretty simple even for a noob. It was my first time using nano.

control+o to save

control+x to exit